# EntityFramework 5 hits database twice within the same context

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, first-level-cache

In MSDN for Entity Framework 5 the .Find Methode is decribed as:

*Uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not in the context then a query will be executed and evaluated against the data in the data source...*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx

But, when i using '.Find' twice within the same context, it **will hit the database also twice**. 
I thought after the first try, the entity is stored in the context. (First Level Caching)
What do i wrong ?

```
using (var myContext = new TestDbContext(connectionstring))
{
    var firstTry = myContext.Artikel.Find(20);
    Trace.WriteLine("First Try:" + firstTry.Id);

    var secondTry = myContext.Artikel.Find(20);
    Trace.WriteLine("Second Try:" + secondTry.Id);
}
```

Sql Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Artikel] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=20

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Artikel] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

Since the 'id' column is of type long, i have to cast it to the right type.

```
var firstTry = myContext.Artikel.Find((long)20);
var secondTry = myContext.Artikel.Find((long)20);
```

Now it works as expected.